# Combined Regression and Classification model fitting -Type Error: None Type Object Not Callable

Tags: tensorflow, regression, typeerror, tf.keras, model-fitting

I am trying to train a model for combined regression and clssification task. My input is has 50 rows and 2 columns (75,2) and I want my output to be a single value from regression and classifying the type from classification. Clasification output has 2 classes A,B encoded as 0,1 respectively. I have normalized and converted all the  train, validation, prediction inputs to arrays. You can see the size and type of my inputs, outputs below

```
print(train_x.shape,train_y_cls.shape, train_y_reg.shape, val_in.shape, val_out_cls.shape, val_out_reg.shape  )
```

(2860, 75, 2) (2860, 1) (2860, 1) (572, 75, 2) (572, 1) (572, 1)

```
print(train_x.dtype,train_y_cls.dtype, train_y_reg.dtype, val_in.dtype, val_out_cls.dtype, val_out_reg.dtype  )
```

float64 int32 float64 float64 int32 float64

I built a model and try to train it as shown below...But I keep getting this "Type Error" which I am unable to figure out

```
data_shape = (75, 2)

# Sequential model
model = Sequential()

# Reshape the input to match the 4-dimensional shape
model.add(Reshape(data_shape + (1,), input_shape=data_shape))

# 2D Convolutional with BatchNormalization
model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(2, 1), activation='relu', input_shape=data_shape))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(2, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(2, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# Flatten 
model.add(Flatten())

# Dense layers with BatchNormalization
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))  # output for classification 
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))  # output for regression

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss=['categorical_crossentropy', 'mean_squared_error'], metrics=['accuracy','mae'])

model.fit(x=train_x, y=([train_y_cls, train_y_reg]), validation_data=(val_in, [val_out_cls, val_out_reg]), batch_size=32,  epochs=30)
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[75], line 1
----> 1 model.fit(x=train_x, y=([train_y_cls, train_y_reg]), validation_data=(val_in, [val_out_cls, val_out_reg]), batch_size=32,  epochs=30)

File d:\Pradyumna_DeltaX\Battery_Data_Codes\batteryenv\Lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback..error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File d:\Pradyumna_DeltaX\Battery_Data_Codes\batteryenv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\polymorphic_function\polymorphic_function.py:926, in Function._call(self, *args, **kwds)
    923   self._lock.release()
    924   # In this case we have created variables on the first call, so we run the
    925   # defunned version which is guaranteed to never create variables.
--> 926   return self._no_variable_creation_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
    927 elif self._variable_creation_fn is not None:
    928   # Release the lock early so that multiple threads can perform the call
    929   # in parallel.
    930   self._lock.release()

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I keep getting this error repeatedly. I tried cecking my data for NaN values, shapes, types etc..Restarted the kernel several times. But not able to get rid of this.
Please let me know if there is any problem with my input shapes or the way I am trying to build or train the model.

Comment: Your model has only one output, you need a Functional model, as Sequential models cannot have multiple outputs.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thank you for that....Yes that was one of the major mistakes that was giving me trouble. ..Now its solved.